# Tcl: replace string in a specific column

Tags: tcl

I have the below line:

```
      ^      1        0.02199   0.03188     0.03667     0.00136     0.04155     0.00000     1.07223  1.07223  -0.47462     0.00335      -0.46457     buf_63733/Z              DCKBD1BWP240H11P57PDULVT   -
```

I want to replace column 3 with a different value and to keep the entire line with spaces as is.

I tried lreplace - but spaces deleted.
string map can only replace a word but didn't find a way to replace exact column.

Can someone advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the columns are separated by at least 2 spaces, you could use something like:

```
set indices [regexp -all -indices -inline {\S+(?:\s\S+)?\s{2,}} $line]
set colCount 1
set newValue 0.01234
foreach pair $indices {
    if {$colCount == 3} {
        lassign $pair start end
        set column [string range $line $start $end]
        set value [string trimright $column]
        set valueEnd [expr {$end-[string length $column]+[string length $value]}]
        set newLine [string replace $line $start $valueEnd $newValue]
    } elseif {$colCount > 3} {
        break
    }
    incr colCount
}
```

You can change the `newValue` to something else or the `newLine` to `line` if you don't need the old line.

Answer (score 0):

Another method uses `regsub` to inject a command into the replacement string, and then `subst` to evaluate it. This is like perl's `s/pattern/code/e`

```
set newline [subst [regsub {^((?:\s+\S+){2})(\s+\S+)} $line \
                           {\1[format "%*s" [string length "\2"] $newvalue]}]]
```